# Работа ThreadLocal при обращении к объекту несколько раз из одного и того же потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Если я с помощью Task обращаюсь к переменной с ThreadLocal, после завершения работы потока она(переменная) будет уничтожена? Или останется доступна для этого потока позже?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Время жизни thread local-переменных ограничено лишь временем жизни потока. Так что переменная будет существовать, если поток не умрёт.

Проблема обычно в другом: используя Task, вы не контролируете, в *каком именно* потоке будет выполняться ваш код. Два последовательных запуска даже одинакового Task'а могут выполняться с разных потоках (да и сам Task может мигрировать из потока в поток), так что передавать данные через thread local-переменную — не лучшая идея.

Comment: Все-таки сам Task мигрировать из потока в поток не может.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Почему не может? На любом `await`'е может же. Плюс, понятие «поток, в котором бежит таск», само по себе некорректно. Что если таск ожидает чтения из сети? Что если таск выполняет `await Task.WhenAll(...)`, а ожидаемые задания бегут в разных потоках?

Comment: Задача вообще редко когда считается выполняющейся... https://ideone.com/N2YSyH

Comment: @VladD Мне оно и надо. Я хочу сделать вызов метода в много потоке не Box.Push("объект,"объект, который толкают","объект, который толкает"), а Player.Box("имя объекта, который толкают"). Push(). Т.е до этого создал игрока, а потом вызывают от его имени подобные методы. Метод Box возвращает объект Box,который и является ThreadLocal. В итоге не нужны блокировки и тратится меньше времени на инициализацию объектов

Comment: @Arantler: Передача ссылки на объект в Task занимает дополнительно несколько наносекунд. Вы экономите на спичках.

Comment: @VladD тут ещё стоит вопрос удобства...Это возможно реализовать?

Comment: @Arantler: Если вы запускаете Task, вы **не знаете**, в каком потоке он будет отрабатывать. Так что это не вопрос удобства. Это вопрос правильности. Ну и далее, параметры метода — это всегда лучше, чем глобальные переменные. Вы хотите по сути передавать информацию через глобальную переменную. Так делать не стоит.

Comment: @VladD Немного не понял глобальные и локальные переменные, где они тут?Да, я не знаю в каком потоке, но мне и не надо, разве нет? Про удобство я имею ввиду, что я логически красиво даю задачу. Т.е не Box.Push(player,box), а Player(name player). Box(name box).Push(). Для этого и спрашиваю. Насколько я понял, Task не всегда делает все в одном потоке... Можно ли сделать красив или придется не красиво Статик юзать? О, а можно подобное со старик методами и классами провернуть

Comment: @Arantler: Thread local — это на самом деле глобальная переменная. Она глобальная не по всей программе, а только в потоке, но это не намного лучше. Ну то есть если один таск выполняется в одном потоке, а другой в другом, то второй таск не увидит thread local-переменную. И я совсем не понял ваш синтаксис насчёт Player и Box — можете привести определения классов?

Comment: @VladD https://ideone.com/lQjJ0O это пример не статик. И возможно я сформулировал задачу . Мне нужно каждой задаче, которая обращается к переменной Box выдать объект Box. Он с ним работает и пока не завершит работу, не отпускает. После он просто перестает его занимать. Потом другая задача может его взять.

Comment: @Arantler: Ну хорошо, это понятно, а причём тут thread local? Где тут многопоточность? И где тут Task?

Comment: @VladD Попытка решить задачу. Не понял. Как раз Task используется для вызова метода. Их тут нет, потому что это определения самих классов.

Comment: @Arantler: Окей, а что должно произойти, если пока одна задача что-то делает, другая обращается за Box'ом?

Comment: @VladD вот это я пытаюсь решить. И да, хотел Box`у locker передать. Но между вызовами может прийти другой поток...